# How to call a function in python GUI window?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a project for face recognition, but when on my GUI i click on the start button to check for facial recognition it is opening another window for the camera, and i want it open the camera on the same window what should I do?

Here is the code I am working on

```
import os

from tkinter import *


window = Tk()
window.title("IntrudeX")
window.configure(background="black")

def run():
    os.system('WebCamFaster.py')
def exit():
    sys.exit()

photo1 = PhotoImage(file="fa.gif")
Label(window, image=photo1,bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
Label(window, text="Press Start Button for FaceRecognition", bg="black", fg="white", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
Button(window, text="Start", width=6, command=run) .grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
Button(window, text="Exit", width=4, command=exit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=N) ,
window.configure(background="darkgrey")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: using `os.system` you start separated program. You should rather import functions  from other script - `import WebCamFaster` - and run function - `WebCamFaster.some_funtion()`. But it still will need changes to run loop which get image from camera and put in `Label`.

Comment: get image from camera using CV and display in tkinter. [furas/python-examples/cv2/tkinter-CV](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/cv2/tkinter-CV/main.py)